# Where's the official Python API documentation for TF?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, documentation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The web article http://wiki.ros.org/tf only seems to point to the C++ API documentation (e.g. the following sub-article http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Data%20Types only contains C++ examples). I would like to use Python instead. I would like to read the official Python documentation for `tf`. Where can I find it?

In other ROS Wiki pages, there's usually the possibility to see both the Python and C++ version of the code or documentation. Why doesn't  http://wiki.ros.org/tf provide such a duality?

I know there are a few `tf` tutorials (e.g. http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29) which use Python, but I would like to see all other examples and documentation in Python. There's this page http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html, but it doesn't seem to be official.

I have also seen that there's also a new Python interface to the new tf library, i.e. to `tf2`, which is called `tf2_ros`. However, the documentation is pretty much empty. For example, the class [`TransformBroadcaster`](http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/tf2_ros/html/python/tf2_ros.html#transformlistener) is not documented. Why? Why aren't people putting some effort on the documentation?

Furthermore, there's also the following article http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython, but there's no link from the web page http://wiki.ros.org/tf to it, besides being very poorly written and very incomplete.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287826/where%27s-the-official-python-api-documentation-for-tf?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the pages listed by @nbro are linked directly from the *Package Links* linkbox to the right of the *Package Summary* header on the `tf2_ros` [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros):

[image: package links]

which takes you to:

[image: tf2 doc]

All ROS pkgs with (Doxygen) API docs should have those links.

You should not need to search `docs.ros.org` yourself (but you can, of course).

---

Edit1: there is actually a tutorial about this: [Navigating the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheWiki).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-10**:
It's incredible I have never noticed "Code API" on that side of a ROS wiki article. If I am the only one who missed it, then shame on me, but if there are many other people in my situation, shame on the designers of the ROS wiki.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
"shame"? Really?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-04-10**:
@gvdhoorn FYI I've given @nbro an official warning relating to this and a few other posts. https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/161#issuecomment-380206764

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-10**:
To be clear: I don't mind frank discussions and stating of opinions (I'm Dutch, I actually appreciate it). I do believe however that one needs to be careful not to come off as harsh or abrasive. This could just be a matter of the 'email effect', but expressions such as "shame on .." are a bit much.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-12**:
Yes, I understand that there may be a tutorial. My point is: there should not exist the need for a tutorial for such a basic functionality. Don't you also think?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
Every person is different. What may be apparent or intuitive to one could be opaque to another. I guess the tutorial / guide exists to explain how the wiki is layed out so that it becomes easier to find what you are looking for.

I can't comment on whether or not the current layout is bad or not, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
.. as I feel I'm too accustomed to all of this already to really have an objective opinion.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-12**:
There are fields like human-computer interaction (HCI) and user-experience design (UXD) which exist to solve this kind of problems.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-12**:
Certainly. Perhaps you know of a way to get them involved? This is largely a community based project, so improvements should really come from the community.

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2018-04-12**:
This discussion seems to revolve around where the existing documentation can be found. But it doesn’t, in my opinion really address the original questions, which point to the fact that the existing documentation could use some work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-13**:
I'm not sure: the title of the post by the OP is:

> Where's the official Python API documentation for TF?

that does seem to ask for where it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's the [official documentation for `tf`'s Python API](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html) and here's the link for [`tf2`'s Python API documentation](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2/html/) (both for Kinetic).

---

The URL structure is

`http://docs.ros.org/<ros-distro>/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html`

for `tf` and

`http://docs.ros.org/<ros-distro>/api/tf2/html/`

for `tf2`.

Just change the `<ros-distro>` portion of the URL to get your desired version of the docs.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-07**:
@jayess The documentation exists for different ROS versions. I would encourage you to edit your answer and include the documentation for each ROS distribution and not just for kinetic (even though I added the tag only for kinetic, but apparently I can't add more tags).

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-07**:
Note that the second template URL is equal to the first one!